# finding out the number of arrays in a 2d array

Tags: python, arrays

I want my program to find out the number of arrays inside the array `workout`

In this example, there are 4 arrays, so the expected output should be 4.
However i am currently getting the output `449`

The array `workout` looks like this:

```
[['Cable Crossover', 'Cable Flies', 'Incline Bench Press', 'Incline Chest Press Machine', 'Close Grip Benchpress', 'Overhead Dumbell Extensions'], 
['Dumbell Front Raise', 'Dumbell Overhead Press', 'Barbell Overhead Press', 'Reverse Flies', 'Smith Shoulder Press'], 
['Close Grip Pulldown', 'Half Rep Curls', 'One Arm Cable Pull', 'Upright Row', 'Bent Over Rows', 'Rack Pulls'], 
['Leg Curls', 'Squats', 'Leg Extensions', 'Rear Kicks', 'Calf Raisers']]
```

The code i used to generate the output `449` is this:

```
    workout=user_information[4]
    print (len(workout))
```

Any ideas why i am getting this strange output and what i need to change in order for the output to be the number of arrays inside `workout` (which is 4)

`user_information` is an array which includes various information the user registered with. The 4th index in the array contains the generated workout for them.

`print (user_information)` gives this output:

```
['dominic', 'dominic123', '70`', 'strong', "[['Cable Crossover', 'Cable Flies', 'Incline Bench Press', 'Incline Chest Press Machine', 'Close Grip Benchpress', 'Overhead Dumbell Extensions'], ['Dumbell Front Raise', 'Dumbell Overhead Press', 'Barbell Overhead Press', 'Reverse Flies', 'Smith Shoulder Press'], ['Close Grip Pulldown', 'Half Rep Curls', 'One Arm Cable Pull', 'Upright Row', 'Bent Over Rows', 'Rack Pulls'], ['Leg Curls', 'Squats', 'Leg Extensions', 'Rear Kicks', 'Calf Raisers']]"]
```

EDIT: I tested this with another when `workout` contains 6 arrays, and it outputted `693`.

Comment: restart your kernel and try again.

Comment: len(workout) gives me 4 (BTW, in Python, they're called `lists`)

Comment: Prints 4 for me.  >>> workout = [['Cable Crossover', 'Cable Flies', 'Incline Bench Press', 'Incline Chest Press Machine', 'Close Grip Benchpress', 'Overhead Dumbell Extensions'], 
... ['Dumbell Front Raise', 'Dumbell Overhead Press', 'Barbell Overhead Press', 'Reverse Flies', 'Smith Shoulder Press'], 
... ['Close Grip Pulldown', 'Half Rep Curls', 'One Arm Cable Pull', 'Upright Row', 'Bent Over Rows', 'Rack Pulls'], 
... ['Leg Curls', 'Squats', 'Leg Extensions', 'Rear Kicks', 'Calf Raisers']]
>>> print(len(workout))
4

Comment: restarted and am stil getting the same issue

Comment: Added some more code which may be the issue causing it

Comment: The example shown above is pretty confusing. What is user_information? It couldn't be the `workout` list because `[4]` would be OOB.

Comment: Print (workout) instead of the length - does it print a list with 4 items? Maybe the list is being generated incorrectly.

Comment: This question needs an *entirely* self-contained snippet that we can copy and paste to reproduce the problem. We don't have enough information to answer right now.

Comment: It does print the list 4 times - the output of `workout` which i gave you above shows the result of `print (workout)`

Comment: check the edits. It shows what user_information is

Comment: can you please provide the user_information array/ list structure

Comment: `user_infortmation` is an array. my program appends items in a csv file to `user_information`. I have shown above what it looks likle

Comment: Ok len() fuction return list of item in array/list so in your case if you save information of user_information 4th index array it shoudl retrun the number of that array item.There might be other problem that you are missing
 May be print(len(str(workout))

Comment: You are printing len(str(workout)) and posting the wrong code here. But your user_information has quotes around it, so it is str(workout). You posted what you thought it was, not what it actually was. Put quotes around workout, and you will reproduce.

Comment: no. i am setting `workout` to the 4th index of user information, which is the big 2D array containing workout exercises. You can see this array up above both when `user_information` is printed and when `workout` is printed. Read the whole post and it will make sense.

Comment: Check the edits

Comment: Please help i still need an answer to this! @KennyOstrom

Comment: okay sec, I'll write it up. It would be easier if you just believe me when I tell you quotation marks make it a string.

Answer (score 1):

Python is right. You are wrong. Quotation marks make it a string.

```
info = ['dominic', 'dominic123', '70`', 'strong', "[['Cable Crossover', 'Cable Flies', 'Incline Bench Press', 'Incline Chest Press Machine', 'Close Grip Benchpress', 'Overhead Dumbell Extensions'], ['Dumbell Front Raise', 'Dumbell Overhead Press', 'Barbell Overhead Press', 'Reverse Flies', 'Smith Shoulder Press'], ['Close Grip Pulldown', 'Half Rep Curls', 'One Arm Cable Pull', 'Upright Row', 'Bent Over Rows', 'Rack Pulls'], ['Leg Curls', 'Squats', 'Leg Extensions', 'Rear Kicks', 'Calf Raisers']]"]
workout = info[4]
if 4 != len(workout):
    # what how can this be? It's a list!
    if isinstance(workout, list):
        print 'OMG I found a bug in python!'            
    if isinstance(workout, str):
        print 'Oh crap, there were quotation marks.'
```

> Oh crap, there were quotation marks.

If you happen to have python2 you can execute the string as python code with eval:

```
workout_as_list = eval(workout)
print (len(workout_as_list))
```

> 4

So yes, it would have had length 4 if it were a list, but it's not a list. It just kind of looks like one. There is a good chance you wanted it to actually be a list, in which case there was a bug in the code which generated user_information.

Comment: How can i fix this then. I originally declare user_information like this `user_information=[] `, so it should be an array right. My program then pulls values from a csv file and appends it to `user_information`. So how do i get `user_information[4]` to be passed into `workout` as a list.

Comment: That's another question. Check the docs on csvreader (I assume that's what you used). But it reads text, not python code. You'll have to parse it.